# USB Pen not identified

Tags: usb-drive

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and I have a SanDisk Extreme 64GB drive which is not recognized by the system.

`lsusb` command list the drive. but `fdisk` does not show it.

Also no `dev/sd*` could be found

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please clarify your message (and maybe turn it into a question): does the same drive work on a different PC or different operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. I accidently interrupted the formating of the pendrive.But you can try to attach to the other computer or OS, just make sure the pendrive is faulty.

Comment: I tried it on windows and mac, same result

Comment: I guess your pendrive is broken.